# How to map multiple foreign key from ER model to relational model?

Tags: sql, database, foreign-keys, entity-relationship

I have an issue mapping an ER model into relational model. I try to simplify my case.
Supposing to have 3 entities, A, B and C, and 2 relations, R1 and R2

```
[A] ---(1,n) <<R1>>(1,1) === [[B]] === (1,n)<<R2>> (1,1) ==== [[C]]
```

A has a key, ak and other attributes.
B is weak and is identified by ak and bk (this a wek/partial key)
Up to now .. all ok for mapping, I will have 2 relations

- A(ak, a1, ...., an) ak as primary key
- B(bk, ak, b1, ..., bn) with (bk, ak) as primary key and ak foreign key referencing A(ak)

What for C?
I think that C has ck like partial key, but how map the new relation?

C (ck, bk, ak, c1, ..., cn) with

- (ck, bk, ak) as primary key, bk as foreign key referencing B(bk) and ak referencing B(ak)?
- (ck, bk, ak) as key, bk as foreign key referencing B(bk) and ak referencing A(ak)?

or something else like e.g.:

- C (ck, bk, c1, ..., cn) with (ck, bk) as key, bk as foreign key referencing B(bk)?

Thinking on final SQL doesn't help much, since I think that multiple foreign_keys aren't permitted (eg. FOREIGN KEY (bk,ak) REFERENCES B(bk, ak)

I searched on many books but haven't found a similar situation. I'm really confused at this time...
I hope you may help me :-)
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have an image of the ERD?

Comment: You dont want having multiple combined primary keys which will lead to their copy in a referencing table. You should introduce surrogate single field id primary keys and reference them and probably combine these fields into a unique index.  Read more about db normalization and normal forms. Hope it helps.

Comment: @SergeyBenner: Surrogate vs natural keys is a very much heated discussion. There are pros and cons on both sides, depending on many variables.

Comment: Thanks both, Sergey and ypercube. Your answer confirms to me that there are more ways of think about this argument, probably implying a tred-off solution.

Comment: Except that natural keys bloat a db with unneeded fields and indexes that is all that matters to me IMHO. I have never seen a good db designed with a bunch of natural primary keys . Perhaps it makes  sense on very small databses.

Comment: @SergeyBenner: I've designed table that had 11 billion rows added in 2 years (3 million per minute) that had a 15 column natural key. The *use* of surrogate vs natural is **off topic** here: ask a question on http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions for a fuller discussion

Comment: Actually I think it makes sense in very big databases. (provided that the natural keys as narrow, performance should be better with compound keys that by having a surrogate primary key in every table).

Comment: @ypercube: we had no child table and no 2ndary indexes. Also, some columns were NULL so we use a unique clustered not a PK.

Comment: well you just proved what I said. Unreferenced single table with a big natural key. Works for me too. :) but as you said enough of that sorry for offtoping it.

Answer (score 1):

The `PRIMARY KEY` of table `B` is `(bk, ak)` so this is what you should be referencing from `C` for a `1:n` relationship:

```
(ck, bk, ak) as PRIMARY KEY,
(bk, ak) as FOREIGN KEY referencing B(bk, ak)
```

This is allowed in SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE C
( ck, bk, ak, ...
, PRIMARY KEY (ck, bk, ak)
, FOREIGN KEY (bk, ak) 
    REFERENCES B (bk, ak)
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, now I can go on quieter. But in real work, is this a good practice, having a compund primary key in table C? I think is better to have a new primary key as long, and mantein the (ak, bk) as foreing key... is it correct?

Comment: There are pros and cons on both sides. See very many related questions: [Surrogate vs. natural/business keys](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Surrogate+vs+natural+keys)

Comment: I prefer natural keys as much as possible. But good practise is to have narrow Primary Keys. So, if these `ak, bk, ck` are `VARCHAR(200)` they are obviously not very good for making a (or parts of a) Primary Key. If they are simple integers or `CHAR(5)` they wouldn't be a performance problem.

Comment: One advantage of compound keys in cases like yours is that you can use less join in some queries. Imagine you want to show data from tables `A` and `C` only (not `B`) and you have a new surrogate primary in `B`. You'll have to join all 3 tables with `A JOIN B ON B.ak = A.ak JOIN C ON C.New_B_pk = B.New_B_pk` which is much less efficient that what you'd use with the original design: `A JOIN C ON C.ak = A.ak` (one less Join operation and no look up on the indexes of table `B`.)